# Binding to ViewModel instance from View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, binding, viewmodel

I have program which initializes PersonsViewModel in MainWindowViewModel's constructor.

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    PersonsViewModel viewModel = new PersonsViewModel();
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml, PersonsViewModel and PersonsView are connected.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonsViewModel}">
        <vw:PersonsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I use viewModel as ItemsControl ItemsSource.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding viewModel}" Margin="4" />
```

Now my program opens UserControl and I need to set instance of PersonsViewModel to UserControl.DataContext.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:PersonsViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Am I creating a new instance of PersonsViewModel. If I am doing so, then how I can bind it to PersonsViewModel instance? Because I have following code in UserControl. I have PersonsList bound to ItemsSource and I need to bind Command to PersonsViewModel instance.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsList}">                                            
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Content="Ok" Width="20" Margin="3" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the UserControl.DataContext and Add ItemsControl.ItemTemplate. Since each ItemsControl is bound to List of person viewmodel. Each item will get the viewmodel as its datacontext. Refer the below code.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" Margin="4">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonsViewModel}">
        <vw:PersonsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```